# This R code produces a missing value where TRUE/FALSE error

Tags: r

This code produces an error:

> Error in while (diff < limit) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE
>   needed

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
limit <- 0.05
diff <- 0
ppm <- rep(NA,20)
while(i[1]<=nrow(list)) 
{
  while(diff < limit) ##This is where the error is occurring
  {
    if(j==0)
       ppm <- rep(NA,length(ppm))
    ppm[j] <- list$ppm[i]      
    j <- j+1
    if(j > 1)
       diff <- ppm[j]-ppm[j-1]
  }
  print(ppm)
}
```

Now i have found that this is usually because the condition in while is evaluating to NA and hence while cannot check for TRUE/FALSE. But in this case i really don't see what the error is.

Comment: The `debugging` tag is for questions about debugging. It's not for where you want us to do your debugging for you.

Comment: Didn't realize that. Removed the tag now.

Comment: If you want this question re-opened you might try rephrasing it as "what would be a good way to go about debugging this kind of problem"? (Hint: if manually tracing the logic doesn't do it, debugging statements with `cat` as shown below can help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your first time through the `while` loop:

- `j` is 1, `ppm[1]` gets set to the `i`th (first) element of `list$ppm`
- `j` gets incremented to 2
- `j` is now > 1, so you take the difference between `ppm[2]` **which is still `NA`, since `ppm` was initialized to `NA` and `ppm[2]` hasn't been touched yet** and `ppm[1]`; the result is `NA`

Now go back to the top of the `while` loop and compare `diff` (now `NA`) with `limit` (fixed at 0.05) ... boom.

```
i <- 1
j <- 1
limit <- 0.05
diff <- 0     ## diff() is a built-in, probably avoid ...
ppm <- rep(NA,20)
list <- data.frame(ppm=1:10)  ## list is a built-in, probably avoid ...
while(i[1]<=nrow(list))   ## why i[1] ??? why not just i ???
{
  while(diff < limit) ##This is where the error is occurring
  {
    if(j==0)  ## as DWin says: never true, j is initialized to 1
       ppm <- rep(NA,length(ppm))
    ppm[j] <- list$ppm[i]      
    j <- j+1
    if(j > 1) {  ## always true if j is initialized to 1 and incremented the first time
      diff <- ppm[j]-ppm[j-1]  ## will be NA if ppm[j-1] is NA
      cat(j,ppm[j-1],ppm[j],diff,"\n")  ## debugging statement!
     }
  }
  print(ppm)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell ppm will never be initialized inside the `while(){}` since 'j' will never ==0. I also do not see where 'i' is being incremented. (You might consider offering `head(list$ppm)`.

I suppose I could be wrong here (since you never describe the goal) but maybe all you really want is:

```
diff.ppm <- diff(list$ppm)
diff.ppm[1:which.min(diff.ppm >= limit)]
```